# JQuery.ajax/asp.net: if the called page returns the parameters it works but if it performs a linq query then it fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

So I'm really lost on this one and would be much appreciative of some help.

Here's what I'm trying to do: the user submits a form. the second javascript bit below sends form data to a page which submits the information to the database without refreshing the page. This works fine and then calls UpdateResponseText(). UpdateResponseText calls a page which retreives the information (the c# code below) and writes out some string. This value should appear in an alert() box.

Here's the problem: The page Article/GetResponse works fine. I can type in the url manually and get the expected result. However, the "success" portion of UpdateResponseText() never fires so the javascript, I'd believe, has a problem. What's odd though is if I DON'T use the SQL and just Response.Write the parameters then it works.

Here's the Javscript:

```
            function UpdateResponseText() {
                alert("Function Called");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))/Article/GetResponse",
                data: "UserID=@Model.UserInfo.ID&ArticleID=@Model.Content.KEY",
                    success: function (json) {
                        alert("Success");
                    alert(json);
                }
            })
        }
            $('#ArticleFeedbackForm').submit(function () {
                var formdata = $(this).serialize();
                alert(formdata);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "#",
                    data: formdata,
                    success: function () {
                        UpdateResponseText();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

The C#:

```
    public void GetResponse(string UserID, string ArticleID)
    {

        HelpSiteEntities1 db = new HelpSiteEntities1();
        var ARID = Convert.ToInt32(ArticleID);
        FeedbackObject TheFeedbackObject = new FeedbackObject();
        var QuestionQuery = (from Q in db.Questions
                             join U in db.QuestionMaps
                             on Q.ID equals U.QuestionID
                             where U.TopicID == ARID
                             select new { TheQuestionText = Q.Question1, TheQuestionID = Q.ID }).ToList();
        var QuestionID = (QuestionQuery.Select(o => o.TheQuestionID).ToList()[0]);
        //Response.Write(UserID + ARID.ToString() + QuestionID);
        var AnswerOptionsQuery = from A in db.QuestionAnswers
                                 where (A.MapsToID == QuestionID)
                                 select new { TheAnswerText = A.AnswerText, TheAnswerIDs = A.ID, IsStatic = A.StaticResp };
        var AnswerOptions = AnswerOptionsQuery.ToList();
        var previousResponse = (from x in db.QuestionRespMaps
                                where x.UserID == UserID && x.QuestionID == 1 && x.TopicID == ARID
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();
        if (previousResponse != null)
        {

            Response.Write("You have indicated previously \"" + (AnswerOptionsQuery.Where(o => o.TheAnswerIDs == previousResponse.AnswerID).ToList())[0].TheAnswerText + "\". You may update your response below at any time.");
        }
        else
        {
           Response.Write("");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an error function ?

```
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                HandleJQueryError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        ,
            success: function (jsonResponse) {
                UpdateResponseText(jsonResponse);
            }









    function HandleJQueryError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        try {

            var msg = "";

            if (null != jqXHR) {

                if (null != jqXHR.responseText) {
                    msg += "\n\r " + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                if (null != jqXHR.responseXML) {
                    msg += "\n\r " + jqXHR.responseXML;
                }

                try {
                    if (null != jqXHR.statusText) {
                        msg += "\n\r " + jqXHR.statusText;
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                    msg += "\n\r " + err;
                }

            }

            if (null != textStatus) {
                msg += "\n\r " + textStatus;
            }

            if (null != errorThrown) {
                msg += "\n\r " + errorThrown;
            }

            alert(msg);



        }
        catch (err) {
            //alert("HandleJQueryError Error");
            if (null != err) {
              alert(err);


            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be something like that. So here's the result with that code in place:
"
You have indicated previously "TestB". You may update your response below at any time.
 OK
 parsererror
 SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

I'm going to keep working on it based onthose results. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget the up-vote and "mark as answer" when you find a resolution.  I'd also advise getting firebug or chrome developer tools too see what is going "across the wire.  and/or Fiddler2.

Comment: Sure thing. That helps a lot

Comment: For future reference: I had a misunderstanding of how JSON worked. The error handling above pointed to a syntax error... looking into that I realized I wasn't forming a proper JSON response (well, any at all really). The code was changed to produce a response of the form: "response" : "textToPrint"
which could then be accessed with my javascript as json.response

Comment: Update (append at the bottom) your final working code....for future readers.....would be my suggestion.